# Console error: Mixed content, but I can't find the link in the code

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, broken-links

I've been trying to switch a website to HTTPS, but I am blocked on a mixed content warning, where an image still has an normal HTTP URL. The problem is that I can't that image and neither can I find the code that references it.

This is my website: https://joday.ro/ro/

And this is the warning: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://joday.ro/ro/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://joday.ro/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/pexels-photo-417273.jpeg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

I couldn't find it using View page source, nor with the file manager. I'm guessing it might be part of a script, but I have no idea where that would be.

Any thoughts on how to find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your http photo is in the following css file:

https://joday.ro/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-4137.css?ver=1567407956

in the .elementor-motion-effects-layer css class